# Excel lookup not working as I expected

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have this:

```
d   a   1   =VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$C$5,1)
e   b   2   =VLOOKUP(A2,$B$1:$C$5,1)
f   c   3   =VLOOKUP(A3,$B$1:$C$5,1)
g   d   4   =VLOOKUP(A4,$B$1:$C$5,1)
h   e   5   =VLOOKUP(A5,$B$1:$C$5,1)
```

But its gives me this:

```
d   a   1   4
e   b   2   5
f   c   3   5
g   d   4   5
h   e   5   5
```

When I expect this:

```
d   a   1   4
e   b   2   5
f   c   3   N/A
g   d   4   N/A
h   e   5   N/A
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the *range lookup* parameter (`FALSE`) to your formula to find an exact match.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$C$5,1,FALSE)
```